# How to store firebase token in Vuex store

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to store the accessToken that comes back from Firebase into the Vuex store in my Vue project when I run the code I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined

It looks like it's not picking up store.js in the code below, any ideas why that might be?

Thanks

Login.vue

```
mounted: function() {
    Firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged( user => {

        if (user) {
          user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
            this.$store.commit('setStoreToken', idToken)
            return idToken
          });

        }
        else {
          .
          .
          . 
        }
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    loggedIn: false,
    accessToken: '',
  },
  mutations: {
    loggedIn () {
      this.state.loggedIn = true
    },
    loggedOut () {
      this.state.loggedIn = false
    },
    setStoreToken(state, accessToken) {
      state.accessToken = accessToken
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getAccessToken: state => {
      return state.accessToken
    }
  },
})
```

main.js

```
import store from './store.js'

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 3):

My guess:

```
   user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
     this.$store.commit('setStoreToken', idToken)
     return idToken
   });
```

You dont use an arrow function, that means that `this` is binded to the function itself you can either use an arrow function or you create a variable infront of it like this `const self = this`

```
   user.getIdToken().then((idToken)=>{
     this.$store.commit('setStoreToken', idToken)
     return idToken
   });
```

Or you do it like this:

```
   const self = this;
   user.getIdToken().then(function(idToken) {
     self.$store.commit('setStoreToken', idToken)
     return idToken
   });
```